# php7.0-fpm.service: Main process exited /etc/php/7.0/ or /etc/php/7.1/

Tags: php7, php-fpm, fastcgi

When running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get in red the following error:  *Failed to start The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.*

```
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.0 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.0 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.0-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Job for php7.0-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.0-fpm, action "restart" failed.
● php7.0-fpm.service - The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-10-07 12:01:40 PDT; 7ms ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm7.0(8)
  Process: 15565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
 Main PID: 15565 (code=exited, status=78)

Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi php-fpm7.0[15565]: [07-Oct-2017 12:01:40] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf': No such …rectory (2)
Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi php-fpm7.0[15565]: [07-Oct-2017 12:01:40] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi php-fpm7.0[15565]: [07-Oct-2017 12:01:40] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 07 12:01:40 cubi systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.0-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I noticed that I have `/etc/php/7.0/` and `/etc/php/7.1/` but that only the `7.1` has a `fpm` sub-folder in it. Somehow something must be cross-linked somewhere.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only had the `php7.0` package installed, but you did not had the `php7.0-fpm` package installed. On the other hand it looks like you had the `php7.1-fpm` package. So, depending on what you want to do, there are 2 ways to fix this:

#### Use php7.1 instead of php7.0

```
sudo a2disconf php7.0-fpm
sudo a2enconf php7.1-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

#### Install php7.0-fpm

```
sudo apt install php7.0-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me -- (I am running Ubuntu 17.04)

I did a fresh install after removing php. Over all this added a bunch of new folders. Now I have 5.6 7.0 7.1 and 7.2.

source: [Migrating from PHP 7.0.x to PHP 7.1.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.php)

> For fresh installation on Ubuntu 16.04 (I am running 17.04) If we want
>   to install new version && Remove all php dependencies sudo apt-get
>   remove php*
>
> sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common
>   libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-fpm php7.1-curl php7.1-gd
>   php7.1-bz2 php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-json php7.1-tidy php7.1-mbstring
>   php-redis php-memcached